# Replace black with white in uiview ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, ios10

How can I replace all black in a UIView.

Is there a layer filter or something I can do to replace any black in a UIView with another color such as white?

I am trying to make a  jailbreak tweak that changes text in the widgets to white. But I found that it is a UIRemoteView and I can't see inside to hook the labels. So I was thinking if I could add a filter or something to that RemoteView to replace the black with white.

This is a jailbreak tweak so normal restrictions do not apply.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: your requirements are not clear, please clarify and post your tried code along with.

Comment: @Poles I am trying to replace any black in a uiview.

Comment: @DavidCam What do you mean by "any black in a uiview"?

Comment: David please have a look ..http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @Viabhav Ok here is an explanation. I am trying to make a  jailbreak tweak that changes text in the widgets to white. But I found that it is a UIRemoteView and I can't see inside to hook the labels. So I was thinking if I could add a filter or something to that RemoteView to replace the black with white.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to change color of layer background use the following code:

**Objective C:**

```
myView.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

**Swift:**

```
myView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

Comment: I am not meaning background color. I am trying to replace any black pixels on the screen in the uiview and make them white